# hive query in Job tracker

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hi we are running hive queries in CDH 4 environment to which we recently upgraded. One thing I notice is that earlier in CDH 3 we were able to track our queries in Job tracker.

The link similar to "hostname:50030/jobconf.jsp?jobid=job_12345" would have a parameter "hive.query.string" or "mapred.jdbc.input.bounding.query" which contains the actual query for which the MR job is executed.

But in CDH4 I do not see where I can get the query. Many queries are run in parallel to keep track of which is the query we are concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the query parameters for each job can be found in .staging folder in HDFS itself and can be parsed to get the Job_Ids associated query.

Comment: Being this I am still not sure what should be done to get them reflected in the Jobs xml file, which has all the Jobs parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can still view the hive queries in job tracker.

Get the job information based on the job id from below url         hostname:50030/jobtracker.jsp

You will find some details as mentioned below at the top of the page.

> Hadoop Job 4651 on History Viewer 
>   User: xxxx JobName: test.jar
>   JobConf:
>   hdfs://domain:port/user/xxxx/.staging/job_201403111534_4651/job.xml
>   Job-ACLs: All users are allowed Submitted At: 14-Mar-2014 03:15:19
>   Launched At: 14-Mar-2014 03:15:19 (0sec) Finished At: 14-Mar-2014
>   03:18:04 (2mins, 44sec) Status: FAILED Analyse This Job

Now click the URL next to the Job Conf you will find your submitted hive query.

Comment: Hi , I used to do that earlier in CDH3 I can get all the information in the xml which you mentioned. But in the new version i see only Jar file created but  not the query.